# What is the keystroke to pick the next option up in a list given by auto-completion when using atom editor in Vim mode?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, key-bindings, atom-editor

As I know, when editing a file in Vim, the auto-completion will give a list of possible options for the editor to choose, and `Ctrl+p` allows choosing the previous option while `Ctrl+n` the next option.

Does anyone know the counterparts, except the arrow keys, when using Atom in vim mode?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything besides arrow keys available, but you could override `ctrl-n` and `ctrl-p` key-bindings in `atom-text-editor.autocomplete-active` selector. In order to do that you have to edit `keymap.cson` (search for `Application: Open your Keymap` in Command Palette `Ctrl+Shift+P`) and add this:

```
'atom-text-editor.autocomplete-active':
  'ctrl-n': 'core:move-down'
  'ctrl-p': 'core:move-up'
```

It will trigger only if auto-completion list is active.